# How to read a specific line only if contains a specific data

Tags: lua

Basically im trying to get the last modified timestamp of a file without external libraries

OS: Windows

Code:

```
local cache_out = io.popen("dir /T:W %CD%\\data\\actions\\scripts\\cache.lua", "r")
local cache_data = cache_out:read("*a")
```

It prints:

[image]

My question is: How can start reading from 29/06/2021 to get the modified time which in this case is '04:45'? I know it can be done using **string.find** or **string.gmatch** but i have no clue how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua uses regex with its own classes for matching characters:

```lua
.  -- all characters
%a -- letters
%c -- control characters
%d -- digits
%l -- lower case letters
%p -- punctuation characters
%s -- space characters
%u -- upper case letters
%w -- alphanumeric characters
%x -- hexadecimal digits
%z -- the character with representation 0.
```

To get the class of all characters except the group just use uppercase. For example, if you want to match any character except space (like tab and space) you would use `%S`.

To match multiple parts of a string you can use parenthesis in `string.match()` like so

```lua
local d, t, _ = string.match(cache_data, "(%d%d/%d%d/%d+)%s+(%d%d:%d%d)%s+([ap].m.)")
```

and just validate the data for anything other than `nil`.

For more detailed info I recommend reading this https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html